# Tengo un problema con el código, realizado en opencv,?

Tags: python, opencv

se hace una lectura de carpeta, para igual leer imagenes, de eso abrir imagen y convertir en hsv.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 
import glob
import matplotlib.image as mping
from PIL import Image
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join



path = glob.glob("C:\Users\...\*.JPG") 
cv2_img = []
for img in path:
    n = cv2.imread(img)

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (76, 255,255))
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (76, 255,255))
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (86, 255,255))

    imask = mask>0
    green = np.zeros_like(img, np.uint8)

    kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)

    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)


    green[imask] = img[imask]

    #img=cv2.cvtColor(n,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)                         
    #img=cv2.resize(img,(200,200))
    cv2.imwrite("lagreen3.jpg", img)
    cv2_img.append(n)
```

Comment: Bienvenido Luis Angel Ramirez Flores a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Lo siento, pero no me queda claro que es lo que estás preguntando, mencionas un problema ¿Cuál?